# Multiple assignments to the same register in an RTL block with Kansas Lava

Tags: haskell, vhdl, lava

I'm having trouble understanding Kansas Lava's behaviour when an `RTL` block contains  multiple assignments to the same register. Here's version number 1:

```
foo :: (Clock c) => Signal clk Bool
foo = runRTL $ do
    r <- newReg True
    r := low    
    return $ var r
```

This behaves as I expected it:

```
*Main> takeS 10 foo :: Seq Bool
low | low | low | low | low | low | low | low | low | low | ? .
```

The generated `VHDL` is:

```
architecture str of assignments is
  signal sig_2_o0 : std_logic;
begin
  sig_2_o0 <= '0';
  OUTPUT <= sig_2_o0;
end architecture str;
```

However, I hoped this other version would also work:

```
foo = runRTL $ do
    r <- newReg True

    r := low
    r := high
    return $ var r
```

But it doesn't, and the second assignment isn't taken into account:

```
*Main> takeS 10 foo :: Seq Bool
low | low | low | low | low | low | low | low | low | low | ? .
```

The reason I'm confused is because `reg` and `var` are defined in terms of a full clock cycle, so it's not like I could do impossible-to-synthesize things like branch based on `r` and then reassign a new value to it. So why doesn't this second form work?

It's not just a simulation issue either: the generated `VHDL` for the second version clearly shows that the second assignment is thrown away at generation time:

```
architecture str of assignments2 is
  signal sig_2_o0 : std_logic;
begin
  sig_2_o0 <= '0';
  OUTPUT <= sig_2_o0;
end architecture str;
```

So basically, I would have expected the output to be more like

```
architecture str of assignments2 is
  signal sig_2_o0 : std_logic;
begin
  sig_2_o0 <= '0';
  sig_2_o0 <= '1';
  OUTPUT <= sig_2_o0;
end architecture str;
```

but I'm not sure what that would/should mean in VHDL.

Comment: Where is the VHDL in this question?

Comment: The VHDL is generated by Kansas Lava. I don't think I should include it in the question, because that would be akin to including the generated assembly code when having a programming question...

Comment: Well, VHDL /= assembly language. If it is the VHDL that is behaving or not, then it would be worth posting. For the example shown, it presumably isn't huge.

Comment: OK after looking at the generated VHDL in both cases, this seems to be a purely Lava issue. I'm editing the question to reflect that. I'll still leave the `vhdl` tag because the `lava` tag doesn't seem to get much use, and I'm also interested in what VHDL's view on non-SSA blocks is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using multiple **non-blocking** statements to assign the signal.

```
  sig_2_o0 <= '0';
  sig_2_o0 <= '1';
```

This translates to:

```
at next event assign '0' to sig_2_o0.
at next event assign '1' to sig_2_o0.
```

This is different than using **blocking** assignments:

```
  sig_2_o0 := '0';
  sig_2_o0 := '1';
```

Which would translate to:

```
assign '0' to sig_2_o0.
assign '1' to sig_2_o0.
```

**Blocking assignments**

When you use blocking assignments the value is clearly defined. First it will set to '0', then override it with '1'. In this example there should be no effect from the first blocking assignment for either simulation or synthesized hardware. You can think of it as there is 0 delay between the first assignment and the second. This means you have a pulse of 0 width, which is actually nothing. It is equivalent to having just the last assignment, with the first omitted entirely. One caveat is that if you put a delay on the assignments, e.g. "after 1 ns" then you will notice the first assignment followed by the second in simulation. In hardware, delays are ignored and so there would be no change from adding delays. In fact, inserting delays in RTL that is intended to be synthesized is strongly discouraged for this reason. It is highly desirable that the hardware matches the simulation, and adding delays can introduce mismatches.

**Non-blocking assignments**

But when you use non-blocking assignments the simulator has two assignments scheduled for the next time event. Set the signal to '1' and at the same time, set it to '0'. So which scheduled assignment will the signal take? There is no way to know. It may be either value since it is incorrectly assigned. Every lint checker and synthesis tool on the planet should throw an error when encountering multiple non-blocking assignments like this. It may be possible to simulate it, but there is clearly a problem with the RTL.

Comment: So, two follow-up questions on this:
1. Is there any effect of the first `sig_2_o0 := '0'` in the blocking example? Is it observable either in simulation or in synthesized hardware?
2. Is there an embedding of this kind of blocking semantics into Kansas Lava?

Comment: @Cactus, I added my response to 1 in the answer. About 2, I'm afraid I'm just a RTL guy and don't know much about Kansas Lava so I can't give you the full-picture answer you need. I can only give a partial answer from my understanding of RTL. IMO, blocking vs non-blocking is the most difficult aspect of RTL to understand. It took me a while to get it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Based on this, I think Kansas Lava's codegen would do better to generate VHDL code that only contains the last assignment (so multiple assignments would be a purely codegen-time thing, like they currently are). I'll contact the Kansas Lava developers about this.

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple blocking statements in a single code block it isn't harmful but it does add dead code. Multiple blocking statements can be useful when they are in different code blocks. For instance, you might have a default assignment, then later there is another assignment nested in an if statement. I use that structure a lot in RTL coding and it is nice for concise, efficient RTL.